# Grab data from graph

Tags: r, plot, extract

I have a graph saved as *.jpeg, and I would like to extract data from this such that I can do some analysis.

Since there are lot of images, I would very much like to automate the proces. R seems a natural choice. I see that packages "Digitize" and "ReadImages" are recommned, but I can not install them (on Windows at least).

So, do anyone know of an R-package that will let me extract data from (many) graphs. I would prefer something in R, but other (automated) stand alone applications are welcome.

Comment: the matlab [image processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/) is good for stuff like this if you have access

Comment: devtools::install_url("https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/ReadImages/ReadImages_0.1.3.3.tar.gz")

Comment: The Windows files it needs (see the README in the above URL) are here: http://www.rforge.net/jpeg/files/libjpeg-current-win.tar.gz

Comment: @hrbmstr, I cant install the dependenices

Comment: @hrbrmstr:  Would you mind telling me what I have done wrong?  > library(devtools)
> devtools::install_url("ran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/ReadImages/")
Downloading package from url: ran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/ReadImages/
Error in download(bundle, x$url, x$config) : 
  client error: (404) Not Found

Comment: looks like you forgot a `c` in `cran`